# amsrefs spacing between entries

Tags: bibliographies, line-spacing, amsrefs

I am using amsrefs and would like to increase the spacing between entries.
Is there an easy way to do this.  The parameter bibitemsep doesn't exist, and itemsep has no effect.    Changing line spacing generally also alters the spacing within entries.

Any hints?   Surely there's a one liner that'll do this!

Comment: The entries set by `amsrefs` appear to be ordinary "paragraphs", so resetting `\parskip` to a larger value (be sure to include some stretch) just before the bibliography should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks.   This works perfectly.   It took effect when I included it after "\begin{bibdiv}" and "\begin{biblist}" and before the first "\bib" entry.